# How to change the value of array elements

Tags: java, arrays

```
int A = 300;
int B = 400;
int C = 1000;
int D = 500;

int []abcd = {A,B,C,D};
Arrays.sort(abcd);   // the sequence of array elements will be {300, 400, 500,1000}
```

I wanted to change the value of the variables A,B,C,D according to their location in the array after sorting.

e.g variable A is located at index 0, so the value of A change to 1 instead of 300,
    variable B is located at index 1, so the value of B change to 2 instead of 400,
    variable D is located at index 2, so the value of D change to 3 instead of 500,
    variable C is located at index 3, so the value of C change to 4 instead of 1000,

The final value of the variable will be: 
A = 1;
B = 2;
C = 4;
D = 3;

Answer (score 6):

A naive way to do it would be to go through each element of the array, checking the values as you go:

```
for (int i = 0; i < abcd.length; i++)
{
    if (abcd[i] == A)
    {
        A = i+1;
    }
}
// Rinse and repeat for B, C, D
```

If going down this approach, of course, turn it into a function that accepts the array, the value to search for, and returns its index within the array.

Answer (score 5):

I think you are misunderstanding something about the way that arrays of primitives work. When you create the array int[] abcd = {A,B,C,D}, it does not contain the variables A, B, C, and D, it should contain copies of their values.

Hence, when you sort them, you do not actually have any impact on A, B, C, or D.

One way to accomplish something close to what you are trying to do would be to use a sorted map, where each value would map into a value holder, you can then iterate over the keys (in a sorted order) and assign a sequential number to each value holder.

If you clarify more about what you're really trying to do, it may be easier to help.

Comment: Thanks Uri, I am actually do the array sorting so that it will be easier to located the biggest value of the Variable. Since variable C is the biggest value among other variable, C will change to 4 and its follow to the second biggest value D=3, B=2, A=1.

Comment: Just put the values in an ArrayList, run Collections.sort on it, and pick the last one... thats your max.

Comment: Why not just use Collections.max() ?

Comment: I thought he wanted all of them in order, not just maximized.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the **variables** A, B, C and D have no "location in the array". What you did was to create a blank array with 4 slots, and affect the **values** of those variables in position 0, 1, 2 and 3.

When you sort the array, the **values** (once again) get shuffled between the array's slots, but sort() doesn't know anything about the variables A, B, C and D, so *their* values remain unchanged. If you want those to change, you need to re-affect back the values into the variables, by using each slot's position:

```
A = abcd[0];
B = abcd[1];
C = abcd[2];
D = abcd[3];
```

Comment: I would add that this is true because int's are value types.  Where they reference types, the variables and array elements would point to the same memory on the heap.

Comment: Yes, but sorting would still only shuffle the references in the array, and not change the variables...

Comment: Ahhh, I didn't pay close enough attention to the OP's question.  No, that will not be the case.

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for the syntax of array element access or something more complicated?

In Java,

abcd[2] = 500;
abcd[3] = 1000;

will make the modification you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Don't sort them.  Put them in one array, have a second array initialized to all zeros, and count how many items are greater than or equal to each element.  Then just transfer these counts back to the variables.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a mapping from value to array location.  Unless there's a way to get such a mapping out of Arrays.sort(), which I doubt (though I'm no Java expert), you'll need to generate the mapping yourself.  You could do this by searching the array.  It might be more efficient to implement your own sort so that you can keep track of the mapping as you sort the array.

Answer (score 0):

just loop it to change the value :

```
for(int i=0;i<abcd.length;i++){
      abcd[i] = i+1;
 }
System.out.println(Array.toString(abcd));
```